# Calculate the difference between to date columns of a dataframe

Tags: r

How can I get the difference between `Date1` and `Date2` columns of my dataframe?

```
   Date1        Tfd             Date2       Sex
 13/08/1936      3           09/01/2013      M     
 25/04/1948      2           14/05/2014      M
 26/01/1939      1           03/07/2015      F
 13/02/1935      8           03/08/2012      F
```

I have tryed:

```
age<-apply(df[, c("Date1", "Date2")], function(x, y) difftime(strptime(y, format = "%d.%m.%Y"), strptime(x, format = "%d.%m.%Y"),units="years"))
```

but I get this error:

```
Error in strptime(y, format = "%d.%m.%Y") : 
  argument "y" is missing, with no default
```

Do you know how can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `apply` here :

```
as.numeric(as.Date(df$Date2, "%d/%m/%Y") - as.Date(df$Date1, "%d/%m/%Y"))
#[1] 27908 24125 27917 28296
```

`difftime` does not have `units` as `'years'`. The maximum `units` it has is of weeks. You can divide the week value with 52.25 to get year of use `lubridate`'s `time_length` function.

Or using `dplyr` with `difftime`

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>%
  mutate_at(vars(starts_with('date')), lubridate::dmy) %>%
  mutate(diff = time_length(difftime(Date2, Date1), 'years'))

#       Date1 Tfd      Date2 Sex diff
#1 1936-08-13   3 2013-01-09   M 76.4
#2 1948-04-25   2 2014-05-14   M 66.1
#3 1939-01-26   1 2015-07-03   F 76.4
#4 1935-02-13   8 2012-08-03   F 77.5
```

Comment: @Jeni It selects columns which has date in it (here date1 and date2) and apply function `dmy` to it to change the columns to date.